# define-syntax vs. defining functions

Tags: function, scheme, racket

In Racket, you can define syntax in this way:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ "abc") 'xyz)))
```

By running

```
(foo "abc")
```

It returns 'xyz. Implementing this using define:

```
(define (foo x)
  (match x ["abc" 'xyz]))
```

This time,

```
(foo "abc")
```

still returns 'xyz. What is the difference between using these different forms?

Comment: What *time* do you think each is being computed?  Do you know the difference between *compile* time and *run* time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`define-syntax` defines a macro. Macros are processed at compile time, and produce new code to be compiled, functions execute at runtime. As a result, macros do not have access to runtime variables, and do not evaluate their arguments. To see the difference, try:

```
(define param "abc")
(foo param)
```

with your two ways of defining `foo`. This will work with the function, but not the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define abc "abc")
(foo abc)
```

You will see very different results between the two versions.